# Streaming audio over SSH.

Tags: linux, ssh, streaming, thin-client, audio

I do most of my work over ssh on a remote linux server where I also keep most of my files. I'd like to be able to hear any sounds that normally would be on the PC speaker. Is there a way to have sound be sent through my ssh session along with the terminal display?

Comment: I would suggest PulseAudio, if it weren't such a bandwidth hog.

Comment: @grawity: Just in case: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2145/how-can-i-use-pulseaudio-over-ssh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pulseaudio for streaming audio.

But i would suggest mounting  remote filesystem on a local folder using sshfs and playing files from there.

```
mkdir mountfolder
sshfs username@remotehost:/ mountfolder
```

Comment: thanks for this, it's something I've been wanting to do but too lazy to look up.

Comment: Is there a way to put the system audio though using pulseaudio? I really just want to be able to hear the server beep when I'm highlighted in irssi.